# How can I log into Windows 8 (Microsoft account) whilst offline?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-account

From what I've read, Windows should cache the last used password and I should be able to login even when offline, but this isn't the case -- using my Microsoft password is prompting me to use my last used password, which is in fact what I'm doing!

So, how can I login when I have no internet connection?

**Update**: This problem seems to have just disappeared for me. I could not tell you why — perhaps it's due to an update — but I'm unable to verify any possible answers now.

Comment: Have you logged in once before whilst online?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: My Microsoft Live ID account logs on even where there is no internet connection.  Could I suggest you try another account?

Comment: Strange. Using another account wouldn't really alleviate the problem: I need to be able to get on this account.

Comment: Also having this problem and this isn't fun.

Comment: We don't really make questions community wiki anymore. It's okay to let this question stay. If you can't reproduce it anymore but others have had the same issue, voting will ensure a proper answer floats to the top eventually. You don't have to accept anything if you can't verify it.

Answer (score -1):

When you are logged in to your computer, you should set er numeric PIN.

You can do this by following these steps; 
Press thewindows key + s
Type: PC Settings
Go into Accounts
Choose Sign-in options
Set your pin

Hope this helps

Comment: Please explain exactly how this answers the question ...