# How can I log on to Windows 10 without internet?

Tags: windows-10, login, internet-connection, microsoft-account

I set up a Microsoft account on my Windows 10 computer. Now without warning it won't let me log on without internet access.

It asks me for the last password as I am offline, but will not accept this or the new MS account password.

Surely there must be a way to log on while offline, as there was before I created the account?

Comment: See: [How can I log into Windows 8 (Microsoft account) whilst offline?](http://superuser.com/questions/520083/how-can-i-log-into-windows-8-microsoft-account-whilst-offline)

Comment: Thank you. Odd it didn't seem to show that question while I was typing - it's normally very good at that. Question still stands though.

Comment: Even with a linked account you should be able to log into the account, since the local account still exists, verify your using the correct password

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to login without Internet in Windows 10, the first time you login to your PC with an Internet connection do the following:

Start > Go to your account > a popup will appear > select `Change account settings`

[image: Change account settings]

There will be an option to use local account as administrator, choose that option. The next time you restart your PC, you can login to your PC without an Internet connection.