# Starting Windows 10 without internet connection

Tags: windows-10, internet, login, microsoft

After a recent update to "Windows 10 Home" it seems impossible to log-in without known Internet connection. The procedure is also much longer than before (when Internet available). I searched and found answers relevant to previous updates. Login is thru a Microsoft account.

When starting windows can I log-in to the computer without an Internet connection?

The following answer:

[How can I log on to Windows 10 without internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/1084493/how-can-i-log-on-to-windows-10-without-internet)

does not seem to work for "Windows 10 Home" with recent updates.

Comment: You will need to login with a local account, perhaps the Administrator account? Logging into a Microsoft account without an internet connection, I would think is impossible, unless it's cached somehow.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser :-) I'm sorry but I don't see an actual question there. Maybe you could quickly have a peek at [this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and re-phrase your posting? Thanks :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I log on to Windows 10 without internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/1084493/how-can-i-log-on-to-windows-10-without-internet)